# Permission to attach AKS to ACR without subscription level role?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-aks, azure-cli, azure-acr

I have created a user with contributor role to specific resource group and owner
role to an ACR and an AKS cluster which are both in that resource group.

In spite of this when the user tries to attach the ACR to the cluster with this command
az aks update -n (cluster name) -g  (resource group) --attach-acr (acr name)

It returns this error:
The client xxxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com' with object id xxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroup/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/xxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I have read about a solution to make the user subscription contributor, but I do not want the user to have visibility to anything that is not in the specific resource group.

It is also confusing since the user can view the AKS cluster in the portal, authenticate and view and deploy objects in the cluster.

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is **no need** of assigning subscription Contributor role. I tried assigning same roles as you to **demo user** under resource group and I'm able to attach AKS to ACR successfully. Check [here](https://imgur.com/a/MrZ7GMD).

Comment: Could you please include how you added the role by editing your question with Portal screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the user or service principal specified in the command does not have the necessary permissions to perform the `Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/read` action on the specified AKS cluster. This could be due to a lack of permissions at the subscription, resource group, or AKS cluster level.

You can fix it by verifying few things-
First go to the resource group under which you have created your cluster and container. Let's say for example jhurtas-rg, under that on the left hand side you will see `IAM`
[image]

First check what all access you have already assigned to yourself under `view my access`. Usually, `contributor access` is the one which works.
[image]

**Note** that this same access should reflect in your cluster and container. You can verify those same way as above under IAM of each resource.
If all of them have contributor role enabled, then attaching the acr to your cluster won't be a problem. If at all you don't have the permission, add it by clicking on `add roles`- > `role assignment`-> add this additional role called
`aks contributor`.
[image]

Remember this has to reflect in acr and your cluster as well. Now You try to attach your acr you will see it works

[image]

and can pull images stored in your acr repository
[image]

[image]